# multidimensional array: incompatible type assignment

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, variable-assignment

I have declared array of known size,

```
typedef struct{
  ......
  char * buffer[height+1];    //height is a constant int
  ......} args;

int main{
 args * info;
 info = malloc (sizeof(args));
 char* output_buffer[width][height+1];    //width is also a constant int >= 4
 output_buffer[2] = malloc (sizeof(char)*char_per_line*(height+1)); // error same as below
 info->buffer = output_buffer[2];    // I know it's wrong. incompatible types in assignment
....}
```

Numbers are arbitrary and used just for illustration.

What i am doing is to assign the address of `output_buffer[width]` to `info->buffer`, and then pass `info` as an argument to a thread, which generates data an array of size `height+1`; in each slot is a cstring of length `char_per_line`. Those cstrings are stored in `output_buffer[2]`.

I am confused here that isn't the `output_buffer[2]` a pointer of type `char*[height+1]`? Then why can't I assign address of memory from `malloc` to it?

Also, I know that I cannot assign an array to an array, but how can I get the code work in desired way? If the solution is to use a `char**` as `char*[height+1]`, then how can I access `info->buffer[height]`, say?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the requirement you are specifying, this is what you need to do

```
/* This is a 2D array of pointers. */
char* output_buffer[width][height+1]; 

for ( int i =0; i< width; i++ )
    for ( int j=0; j <height+1; j++ )
        output_buffer[i][j] = malloc (sizeof(char)*char_per_line*(height+1));
```

And then,

```
info->buffer[SOME_VALUE] =  output_buffer[SOME_WIDTH][SOME_HEIGHT];
```

> I am confused here that isn't the output_buffer[2] a pointer of type
>   char*[height+1]? Then why can't I assign address of memory from malloc
>   to it?

`malloc` returns a single dimensional pointer `void*` but as you have noted, output_buffer[2] is not a single dimensional pointer. It is of type `char*[height+1]`.  `[]` adds one more dimension apart from the `*`.

Comment: Yes, that works. Thanks! But I am still thinking about assignment at once without loop. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @AoZ You can, but then what is the use of you declaring a 2D array of pointers ( output_buffer)? If there is an array, I am afraid you cant avoid the loop

Answer (score 1):

> isn't the output_buffer[2] a pointer of type char*[height+1]?

No. `output_buffer[2]` is an array of size `height+1`. Its element type is `char*`.

> Then why can't I assign address of memory from malloc to it?

As you know, you cannot assign to an array.

> array of size height+1; in each slot is a cstring of length char_per_line.
>
> how can I get the code work in desired way?

If you need an array of `(height+1)` C strings, each of size `char_per_line`, you need to allocate `(height+1)` C strings of size `char_per_line`. That is, call `malloc` `(height+1)` times and pass `char_per_line` to each. (There's a way to do it in one call to `malloc` but you probably don't want to do that right now).

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct{
  ......
  char * buffer[height+1];    //height is a constant int
  ......} args
```

this has to be

```
typedef struct{
  ......
  char ** buffer;    //height is a constant int
  ......} args

output_buffer[2] = malloc (sizeof(char)*char_per_line*(height+1));
```

you have to this in a for loop, and for all output_buffer[i][j], (now it is char ** = char *).